# Extracting location in a vector from the result of a function giving location and result

Tags: r

I have a linear regression

```
library(car)
x<-c(1,2,4,5,6,23,5,6,7,8,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,45,3,2,1,3,4,6,7,6,8,9)
y<-c(2,4,5,6,23,5,6,7,8,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,45,3,2,1,3,4,6,7,6,8,9,90)
reg<-lm(x~y)

outlierTest(reg)
outlierTest(reg)$rstudent[1]
#     19 
#9.390998
```

I would like to be able to extract from the result the number 19 (which indicates the possition in x) however I am unsure if is posible to do it directly from the result.

Thank you

Comment: Obvious use of the `which` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 19 you're seeing is a name, and can be accessed with `names`

```
> ot <- outlierTest(reg)$rstudent[1]
> names(ot)
# [1] "19"
```

The corresponding value of `x` is accessed by converting `names(ot)` to numeric and indexing with `[`.

```
> x[as.numeric(names(ot))]
# [1] 45
```